# Creating application pool in Powershell with force option

Tags: powershell, iis, application-pool

I try to create application pool on the remote computer and if it exists already command fails:

> Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerName -ScriptBlock {Import-Module
>   WebAdministration;new-WebAppPool $($args[0]) -Force} -ArgumentList
>   $proj

**Filename:
Error: Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'BIB
'
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-WebAppPool], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Filename:
Error: Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'BIB
'
,Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Provider.NewAppPoolCommand**

So, how can I force creating pool if it exists already?
Or how can I previously check if it exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test if the App Pool already exists, if yes, then remove it:

```
$AppPoolScriptBlock = {
    Import-Module WebAdministration
    if(Test-Path IIS:\AppPools\$($args[0]))
    {
        Remove-WebAppPool $args[0]
    }
    New-WebAppPool $($args[0]) -Force
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerName -ScriptBlock $AppPoolScriptBlock -ArgumentList $proj
```